# RxJava : if/else operation in flatMap

Tags: java, rx-java

I try to get and render some data like below

raw data class

```
  @Data @AllArgsConstructor class Category {
    String name;
    List<String> items;
  }
```

presentation class

```
  @Data @AllArgsConstructor class ViewModel {
    public static final int TYPE_HEADER = 0;
    public static final int TYPE_ITEM = 1;
    int type;
    String category;
    String itemName;
  }
```

and below code is request and transform subscribed data to presentation object.

```
  Observable.create(new Observable.OnSubscribe<Category>() {
      @Override public void call(Subscriber<? super Category> subscriber) {
        subscriber.onNext(new Category("1", Lists.newArrayList("", "a", "b")));
        subscriber.onNext(new Category("2", Lists.newArrayList("")));// this data does not output
        subscriber.onNext(new Category("3", Lists.newArrayList("c", "", "d")));
        subscriber.onNext(new Category("4", Lists.newArrayList("e", "f", "")));
      }
    }).flatMap(new Func1<Category, Observable<ViewModel>>() {
      @Override public Observable<ViewModel> call(Category category) {

        // TODO make this block to one line

        // 1. clean response data and transform to ViewModel    
        List<ViewModel> cleanedItems = Lists.newArrayList(
            Observable.from(category.getItems()).filter(new Func1<String, Boolean>() {
              @Override public Boolean call(String s) {
                return s != null && !s.isEmpty();
              }
            }).map(new Func1<String, ViewModel>() {
              @Override public ViewModel call(String item) {
                return new ViewModel(ViewModel.TYPE_ITEM, null, item);
              }
            }).toBlocking().toIterable());

        if (cleanedItems.isEmpty()) {
          // 2. case : skip
          return Observable.empty();
        } else {
          // 3. case : add header and cleaned data
          return Observable.concat(
              Observable.just(new ViewModel(ViewModel.TYPE_HEADER, category.getName(), null)),
              Observable.from(cleanedItems));
        }
      }
    }).subscribe(new Action1<ViewModel>() {
      @Override public void call(ViewModel viewModel) {
        // render data
        System.out.println(viewModel.toString());
      }
    });
```

output

```
ViewModel(type=0, category=1, itemName=null)
ViewModel(type=1, category=null, itemName=a)
ViewModel(type=1, category=null, itemName=b)
ViewModel(type=0, category=3, itemName=null)
ViewModel(type=1, category=null, itemName=c)
ViewModel(type=1, category=null, itemName=d)
ViewModel(type=0, category=4, itemName=null)
ViewModel(type=1, category=null, itemName=e)
ViewModel(type=1, category=null, itemName=f)
```

I try to write 1, 2, 3 (in comment) statement to 1 line (or more readable way), but I had no idea.
`defaultIfEmpty` operator seems not to use in this case.

Do anyone  have any idea ?

Answer (score 11):

How about this:

```
    public static <T, R> Func1<? super T, ? extends Observable<? extends R>> ternary(
        Func1<T, Boolean> predicate,
        Func1<? super T, ? extends Observable<? extends R>> ifTrue,
        Func1<? super T, ? extends Observable<? extends R>> ifFalse) {
        return (item) -> predicate.call(item)
                ? ifTrue.call(item)
                : ifFalse.call(item);
    }
```

and you use it like this:

```
    .map(CharSequence::toString)
    .distinctUntilChanged()
    .flatMap(ternary(Strings::notNullOrEmpty,
        (kw) -> userRelationshipApi.searchFollowing(kw, null),
        (kw) -> Observable.just(selectedUserListAdapter.getUsers())))
    .subscribe(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK you cannot fullfil it using one line. 
You have to determine if stream is empty and if not emit the items again. You can use cache to avoid double computations.

```
 Observable.create(new Observable.OnSubscribe<Category>() {
            @Override
            public void call(Subscriber<? super Category> subscriber) {
                subscriber.onNext(new Category("1", Lists.newArrayList("", "a", "b")));
                subscriber.onNext(new Category("2", Lists.newArrayList("")));// this data does not output
                subscriber.onNext(new Category("3", Lists.newArrayList("c", "", "d")));
                subscriber.onNext(new Category("4", Lists.newArrayList("e", "f", "")));
                subscriber.onCompleted();
            }
        }).flatMap(new Func1<Category, Observable<ViewModel>>() {
            @Override
            public Observable<ViewModel> call(Category category) {

                final Observable<ViewModel> cleanedItems = Observable.from(category.getItems()).filter(new Func1<String, Boolean>() {
                    @Override
                    public Boolean call(String s) {
                        return s != null && !s.isEmpty();
                    }
                }).map(new Func1<String, ViewModel>() {
                    @Override
                    public ViewModel call(String item) {
                        return new ViewModel(ViewModel.TYPE_ITEM, null, item);
                    }
                }).cache();
                return cleanedItems.isEmpty().flatMap(new Func1<Boolean, Observable<ViewModel>>() {
                    @Override
                    public Observable<ViewModel> call(Boolean aBoolean) {
                        if (aBoolean) {
                            return Observable.empty();
                        } else {
                            return Observable.concat(
                            Observable.just(new ViewModel(ViewModel.TYPE_HEADER, category.getName(), null)),
                            cleanedItems);
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }).subscribe(new Action1<ViewModel>() {
            @Override
            public void call(ViewModel viewModel) {
                // render data
                System.out.println(viewModel.toString());
            }
        });
```

But instead of using rxjava whenever possible, sometimes you can use other api to make code simpler. In you case, you can for example use stream api:

```
.flatMap(new Func1<Category, Observable<ViewModel>>() {
            @Override
            public Observable<ViewModel> call(Category category) {

                List<ViewModel> items = category.getItems().stream().filter(s -> s != null && !s.isEmpty()).map(s -> new ViewModel(ViewModel.TYPE_ITEM, null, s)).collect(Collectors.toList());
                if (items.isEmpty()) {
                    return Observable.empty();
                } else {
                    items.add(0, new ViewModel(ViewModel.TYPE_HEADER, category.getName(), null));
                    return Observable.from(items);
                }
            }
        })
```

Comment: I see the answer is "no", but `cache` operator is useful. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use operator filter() with switchIfEmpty(...)